# como puedo usar validacion de input para pedir un numero positivo y continuar el programa?

Tags: python, python-3.x, entrada, while, booleano

quisiera un output como este:(por cierto preferiria solo el uso de while y expresiones booleanas si es posible. )

```
escribe un numero: -50
debes usar un numero positivo!

escribe un numero: -200
debes usar un numero positivo!

escribe un numero: 200
escribe un segundo numero: -2.5
debes usar un numero positivo!

escribe un segundo numero: 5
escribe un tercer numero: 0
debes usar un numero positivo!

escribe un tercer numero: 200

la suma de tus numeros es x
```

Mi codigo es este:

```
primer_numero=int(input('escribe un numero?'))

segundo_numero=int(input('escribe un segundo numero'))

tercer_numero=int(input('escribe un tercer numero'))

print('la suma de tus numeros es x')

if primer_numero < 0 or segundo_numero < 0 or tercero_numero < 0:
print('debes usar un numero positivo!!')
```

el problema con mi codigo es que te hace las preguntas y si pones un negativo el programa continua.Quisiera que vuelva a preguntar la misma pregunta y que te avise que pongas positivo y ahi recien continue con las siguientes preguntas.

toda ayuda es bienvenida y gracias.(edito:cambie el codigo para que sea mas facil entender)

Answer (score 1):

```
primer_numero = -1

while primer_numero < 0:
    primer_numero = int(input('cuanto quisieras pedir prestado?: '))
    if primer_numero < 0:
        print('Debe ser un numero positivo')

segundo_numero = -1

while segundo_numero < 0:
    segundo_numero = int(input('cual es el interes anual expresado en porcentaje?: '))
    if segundo_numero < 0:
       print('Debe ser un numero positivo')

tercer_numero= -1

while tercer_numero < 0:
    tercer_numero=int(input('cual va a ser tu pago mensual?'))
    if tercer_numero < 0:
       print('Debe ser un numero positivo')

print('primer_nuemro: ', primer_numero)
print('segundo_nuemro: ', segundo_numero)
print('tercer_nuemro: ', segundo_numero)
```

Espero te sirva, seguro hay formas mejores pero por ahora esto servirá

Comment: gracias por responder. buena ayuda.

Comment: De nana. Porfa marca mi respuesta como util dandole a la flecha arriba

Answer (score 1):

Sería conveniente que escribieras la lectura del dato y su validación en una función, de este modo en lugar de tener que repetir el código bastaría llamar a la función tres veces.

Ya puestos, la validación puede ser genérica, de modo que a la función le pases como parámetros los valores mínimo y máximo que deben admitirse para el dato. Si no queremos 
 especificar uno de esos valores (por ejemplo el máximo) podemos poner `None` en ese parámetro para especificar que no existe ese límite. Miraremos también que lo que escriba el usuario sea realmente un entero válido y no cualquier otra cosa, para lo cual capturaremos si se produce una excepción al intentar convertirlo en `int`.

Esta sería la función:

```
def input_entero(prompt, min=0, max=None):
    # Repetimos en bucle infinito la petición del dato
    # En realidad el bucle no será infinito pues al tener un dato válido
    # haremos un return y lo abandonaremos
    while True:
        dato = input(prompt)
        # Verificar que ha escrito un número
        try:
            dato = int(dato)
        except:
            print("El dato debe ser un número entero")
            continue  # Volver al bucle

        # Verificar que hay un mínimo especificado y que lo cumple
        if min is not None and dato<min:
            print("El dato debe ser mayor que {}".format(min))
            continue  # Volver al bucle

        # Verificar que hay un máximo especificado y que lo cumple
        if max is not None and dato>max:
            print("El dato debe ser menor que {}".format(max))
            continue  # Volver al bucle

        # Si todo ha ido bien, salir del bucle retornando el dato
        return dato
```

Que podríamos usar así:

```
n = input_entero("Introduce un positivo: ")
n = input_entero("Introduce un número entre 1 y 10: ", min=1, max=10)
n = input_entero("Introduce un número negativo: ", min=None, max=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

En realidad lo que pides es muy sencillo y se puede abordar de varias formas, una de ellas la que te propongo:

Primero definimos una función que comprueba si el número es entero (y de paso que es un número)

```
def entero(texto):
    while True:
        numero = input(texto)
        if str(numero).isnumeric() and int(numero) = 0:
             return int(numero)
        else:
             print('escribe un numero positivo')
```

Luego tenemos varias opciones, una de ellas sumar los tres números de forma consecutiva y aplicarlo al print

```
resultado = entero('escribe el primer número') + entero('escribe el segundo número') + entero('escribe el tercer número')
print('La suma de tus números es', resultado)
```

Como puedes observar la función nos ahorra tener que escribir código extra

Answer (score 0):

```
def esNumeroPositivo(valor):
    try:
        valor = int(valor)
        if valor > 0:
            return valor
        print("'" + str(valor) + "', no es positivo, intente nuevamente.")
        return False
    except:
        print("'" + str(valor) + "', no es un número.")
        return False

def solicitarNumeros(pregunta):
    respuesta = False
    while respuesta is False:
        respuesta = esNumeroPositivo(input(pregunta))
    return int(respuesta)


numero_uno = solicitarNumeros("Ingrese el PRIMER número por favor: ")
numero_dos = solicitarNumeros("Ingrese el SEGUNDO número por favor: ")
numero_tres = solicitarNumeros("Ingrese el TERCER número por favor: ")
print(numero_uno)
print(numero_dos)
print(numero_tres)

print('La suma de tus números es: ' + str(numero_uno + numero_dos + numero_tres))
```